# Configuring a Dedicated Windows Server 2008 Machine - tomcat5.exe?

Tags: windows-server-2008

Any tips on whether or not tomcat5.exe is necessary for standard Windows Server 2008 operation?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tomcat5.exe is the executable for Tomcat, a Java Container. Its not part of server 2008 and is in no way necessary for it to run, its a third party product, produced by the [apache foundation](http://tomcat.apache.org/) for hosting Java web applications.

If your serving Java web applications though, you do need it!

Comment: The server came with plesk, which I am removing... perhaps that's why it was included with the server.

Thanks for the advice!

Comment: Yep, plesk usually comes with tomcat if your hosting Java services

Answer (score 1):

tomcat5 might be installed with various products -- such as Dell's Server Administration Software, VMWare Server (not ESX/ESXi), some HP printers, some network monitoring systems, etc, etc.  you probably have some software/hardware installed that Tomcat operates as a front end to manage.